# Answer that's beyond the context of a question

Tags: discussion

Recently I've come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330590/2947415), which is related to the question but I think it is an overkill answer for an easy question.

Should I flagged it as low quality?

Comment: Why would you flag it as low quality? Do you think it's *bad*?

Comment: Because the answer doesn't fit to the need of a user? I am not sure about this though. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: And actualy the question is all about .net and he included a `Turbo C++` and `VCL`  he event stated that `you need to convert it to your Language`. Is that okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, flagging it as low quality would be a waste of the Moderators time.

If you think an answer is not useful downvote it.

> I think it is an overkill answer for an easy question.

The author assumed the OP was talking about an external program:

*"...solution that taps into different applicatoin without changing it anyway. but if you have access to the source of MDI app then your way is better :)"*

He just didn't comprehended the question.

Answer (score 1):

He just did not realize that the question is stoopid and has a one-liner solution that's documented everywhere.  He assumed a Higher Standard for SO Q+A and jumped to the conclusion that it needed to be done out-of-process.  A detail that isn't specified in the question.

As such, the answer is not wrong and could, conceivably, be useful to somebody else that googles the question some day.

I personally find it rather difficult to blame users for assuming a high standard at SO.  Don't we all?